# Why do I get the error "System.VisualforceException: Read access denied for ContentNote, controller action methods may not execute."?

Tags: visualforce, contentnote

In a Visualforce page I am outputting fields of `ContentNote` (such as "CreatedDate") using the same pattern that already works for `Note` (and many other types) where the `sob` is a reference to the SObject:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!noteFields.names}" var="f">
    <apex:column value="{!noteWrapper.sob[f]}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

but for any field of `ContentNote` this error is logged:

> System.VisualforceException: Read access denied for ContentNote,
>   controller action methods may not execute.

and the page reports "Insufficient Privileges".

I see nothing that can be set in a profile (and am using a "System Administrator" profile). Also I can (painfully) work around this by indirecting through methods in the wrapper.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Did you check that the current user has salesforce crm Content User Permission?

Comment: @PremAnandh Thanks for the comment. I just checked the SA profile I am using and "Manage Salesforce CRM Content" is checked as is every other permission that has the word "Content" in it. So I think the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Is it possible to paste your controller code ?

Comment: @PremAnandh Not easily as it is spread across multiple classes. I think it is a Visualforce problem not an Apex one based on the message.

Comment: check for your notes weather it is private or not.

Comment: @sanketkumar These are "Enhanced" Notes (AKA ContentNotes) with access controlled via a ContentDocumentLink object.